# Query problem with lookup column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, lookup, corrupt

Setup:

I have two lists on a SharePoint site, A and B.  List A has a column 'b' that is a lookup to the ID field of list B.  I have 500k+ records in A and about 6k records in B.

What works:

I am able to execute a query for items in list A using SharePoint web services, and am even able to filter the query based on a specific "lookup" value for column 'b'.  For example, I can query for items in A whose column b matches 1234 (...<Value Type="Lookup">1234</Value>...), and so on.

What doesn't work:

The query does not work for items older than a specific date, even though my query does not involve dates in any way -- only the lookup column.  Any query on data newer than two years old works fine, anything older than that fails.  If I view items from the SharePoint web page they appear ok, and all the links from child records in B to parent records in A work just fine -- the lookup columns appear intact.

Question:

Is there some kind of maintenance task in SharePoint that can cause some underlying data to get corrupted that can prevent a query based on a lookup id to stop working, like a system restore, etc?  In other words, the lookup column data appears correct on the surface in the web browser.  But does SharePoint represent this value with a GUID or other invisible data that might be out of sync or stale?

Thanks.

Comment: Starting to this this issue is related: http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2009/05/12/spquery-value-type-lookup-fails-on-indexed-columns/.

Comment: Perhaps the day I changed that column from non-indexed to indexed is the day everything went to hell.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are hitting another limit; the maximum number of items retrieved in a query?

See [list throttling](http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2010/04/09/lists-with-larger-size-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling/)

Comment: Thanks.  That would make sense, except for the fact that each query only returns a handful of items (less than 50) anyway.  The IDs of the rows in question are not magic numbers, nor is the date -- no aspect of this is magic.  My only suspicion was that a system restore gone wrong screwed something up.

Answer (score 0):

Try querying by the ID by adding the LookupId=”TRUE” attribute to your FieldRef element.
http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/caml-query-lookup-field-by-id-not-by-value/

Comment: Querying for items above the bad date work fine without LookupID, so I knew it wasn't necessary.  But I tried anyway -- no luck.  It still didn't work.  I tried querying using value types of number, text, etc...nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be related to the fact that the column in question was indexed.  When I removed the index everything started working.  When I reapplied the index, everything kept on working.  I'm attributing this problem to a corrupt index.